# How do I Create a New Application Instance When Calling Another Command From a Console Command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm writing an install task for my application (`php artisan install`); it allows you to configure your .env file, migrate and seed your database, and create an admin user.

However, when I get to the migrate and seed calls via `$this->call($cmd)`, it's using the initial .env settings, not the newly configured settings. I'm guessing this is because the laravel application class is created *before* the .env file is modified by the end-user.

Is there a way that I could either create a new Application context that has the new .env settings or call a console command, telling artisan it should boot up a new instance?